# How can I write a fluent query for full text search?

Tags: sql, laravel, full-text-search, laravel-3

I need to write a fluent query for full text search in Laravel 3.0. The search query goes like this

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE MATCH (tags) AGAINST ('Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet');
```

I had been using Raw query to perform this operation but the results from a raw query could not be paginated. 
Can anyone tell me the right way to write a fluent query for this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this....??

```
public static function find_tags($searchtags, $take = 20)
{
    $results = Posts::raw_where("match (`tags`) against (?)", array($searchtags))
        ->take($take)
        ->get();

    return $results;
}
```

Or just...

```
  $searchtags = "Lorem ipsum blah";
  $results = Posts::raw_where("match (`tags`) against (?)", array($searchtags))
        ->paginate(10);
```

Im just pulling this out of the air though, can't test right now....not at my server...

Comment: Hi again! Can you tell me why this doesnt work?

$results = Posts::raw_where("match (`tags`) against (?)", array($searchtags))->get();

Comment: I thought it did?? doesn't it? or does it only work with take() and paginate()....which I cant see

Comment: Yeah. It doesnt seem to be working with ->get() and even with ->all(). Or may be the result of the query is just of different structure which got messed up in the view... I am trying to figure that out first. Isnt there a prope documentation for this? I couldnt find it anywhere??

Comment: no ...the raw_where is about the only undocumented thing in laravel for some reason....maybe you dont have to get()...like when you do a find(), its just available.....somehow i doubt it, but maybe.

Comment: `raw_where` not working for me. It throws error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::raw_where()` :( anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to perform a raw select statement, all that would have to be written in a raw query is the where() statement. So why don't you try something like this, I'm currently having some issues with my local server so I can't test this by myself but this should work.

```
// If you're using laravel models 
Posts::where_raw(sprintf("MATCH (tags) AGAINST ('%s')", $search))->paginate(10);
```

where_raw is one of laravel's undocumented functions :D, also keep in mind when using raw queries escaping is **not** performed so be careful.

Comment: This did not work out. Its actually looking for a column named "raw" and searching for "MATCH (tags) AGAINST (\'thought\')"

Comment: This is the error message that I got : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'raw' in 'where clause'

SQL: SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `raw` = ?

Bindings: array (
  0 => 'MATCH (tags) AGAINST (\'thought\')',
)